# Prevent a logged in user from looking at other client's orders

Tags: django

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ordered_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey("accounts.CustomUser", 
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                         verbose_name="User", )

class OrderDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,
                      DetailView):
    model = Order

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["object_list"] = self.object.selectedproduct_set.all()

        if context["object_list"].first():
            if context["object_list"].first() != self.request.user:
                return {}


        context["grand_total"] = get_total(context["object_list"])

        return context
```

This is for an online shop. LoginRequiredMixin checks only whether a user is logged in or not. But a logged in user can view somebody else's orders.

That is a user can iterate through orders manually like /orders/15, /orders/16 and have a look at the contents. It is not a secure solution.

To the best of my ability I prevented that by checking if the user is the owner of the order. But this is clumsy: we should send 403 status or something rather than just showing an empty list.

How can I do that?

Comment: Share the `Order` model. How do you link a user to an order?

Comment: @willeM_ Van Onsem, done.

Comment: I've modified this question because it was predicated on the idea that if customer data is leaked from a software system, it is not at all the fault of the engineers that put it together (and it is the fault of "busybody" crackers and hackers). This is not a healthy mindset. The owner of the software (and the people who work on it) need to take full responsibility for their security systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to just pre-filter the queryset with the `Order`s of the `request.user`, this will then return a 404 for `Order`s that do not belong to a user:

```
class OrderDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Order

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(**kwargs).filter(user=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["object_list"] = self.object.selectedproduct_set.all()
        context["grand_total"] = get_total(context['object_list'])
        return context
```

---

**Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).